# Nodejs -Parse Buffer obj

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I have an buffer object coming from a UDP stream (ex.):

```
var string = new Buffer('#0,48,38.017428,49,24.050000,51,70.900*06');
```

The parts i want from the string is:

```
48 : 38.017428
49 : 24.050000
51 : 70.900
etc
```

The first number is the identifier and the second is the data/value. I would like to write separate parser/encoder-files (48.js , 49.js , 51.js , etc..), so I can add more parser later.

I cannot figure out how to "split" the Buffer in to pairs and send it to the appropriate parser. (A function shall first check if a parser is present for the identifier..)

Have tried .split, .match etc....

Any suggestions?

Comment: Will it always be non-binary data like that?

Comment: If the data is just a string, just decode it and use `.split()`

Comment: @mscdex:Yes. The length of the string depends on how many variables (0-150ish) the stream provide

Comment: In that case, you should be able to just `.toString()` on the buffer and then just regular old `.split()` on the resulting string.

Comment: @mscdex:any suggestions on how to "pair" the id and the observation? Array or object??  and how to check for available parsers?